# How to add camera button in keyboard to be use as a Barcode scanner in IOS?

Tags: ios, barcode

How to add camera button in the keyboard to be used as a Barcode scanner in IOS?

Comment: Share your code, if you have tried anything, so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can use a toolbar as an accessoryview of `UITextfield` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`

```
 toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44);
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    spaceItem.width = 130.0;
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(captureBarItemPressed:)];
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: spaceItem, cameraItem, nil];
    [toolbar setItems:items];

txtField.inputAccessoryView  =  toolbar
```